# aws elastic beanstalk websocket error: failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500

Tags: python, django, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am implementing websocket in beanstalk with python-django.

As i understand above error is related to proxy setting.  I have to set proxy in nginx file.  I know i can add nginx via .ebextensions directory. 
But i dont know which exact configuration i needs to add in config file to pass proxy.

My websocket is running on 8080 and websocket url is ws://xx.xx.xx.xx/xxxxxxxxxx/xxx/ws

- I tried to check nginx directory at /etc/nginx directory. But in my beanstalk server it does not exist.